# Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden (Hadoop + S3)

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3

I am trying to Access the s3 files via Hadoop Shell commands and when I execute the below command I getting this error.

What I did so for 
I have installed Hadoop single node (hadoop-2.6.1) and added (hadoop aws jar and aws jdk jar in classpath as well )

**Command I executed**

```
 hdfs dfs -ls s3a://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/azpoc1/
```

**Error**

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-2-211:~/hadoop-2.6.1$ hdfs dfs -ls s3a://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/azpoc1/
-ls: Fatal internal error
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403 Forbidden; Request ID: FC80B14D00C2FBE0; S3 Extended Request ID: TAHwxzqjMF8CD3bTnyaRGwpAgQnu0DsUFWL/E1llrXDfS+CqEMq6K735Koh7QkpSwEe8jzIOIX0=), S3 Extended Request ID: TAHwxzqjMF8CD3bTnyaRGwpAgQnu0DsUFWL/E1llrXDfS+CqEMq6K735Koh7QkpSwEe8jzIOIX0=
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1632)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1304)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1058)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4365)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4312)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1270)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObjectMetadata(AmazonS3Client.java:1245)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:688)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.getFileStatus(S3AFileSystem.java:71)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.getFileStatus(Globber.java:57)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:252)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:1625)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.PathData.expandAsGlob(PathData.java:326)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.expandArgument(Command.java:224)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.expandArguments(Command.java:207)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.processRawArguments(Command.java:190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.shell.Command.run(Command.java:154)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.run(FsShell.java:287)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.main(FsShell.java:340)
```

My core-site.xml file

```
<configuration>

<property>
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://localhost:50000</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
<value>*****</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
<value>*****</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>fs.s3a.impl</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Are you sure that your secret keys need to be published here? I would mask them as ******

Answer (score 2):

First, don't post your secret keys and access keys. This is a significant security risk.

What are the permissions associated with your IAM user? My guess is that it does not have appropriate permissions to access the bucket. I would temporarily give it too many permissions (like s3:*) and see if it works. If it does, then it's permissions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer , I have given the permission like s3:* only. Let me check more the permission , actually I mocked the security keys it's not really one

Answer (score 1):

There's a whole [troubleshooting s3a](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.1.0/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/troubleshooting_s3a.html) document to go through: start there.

There's a also some diagnostics module I've put up which tries to debug connectivity problems *without printing secrets*: [storediag](https://github.com/steveloughran/cloudstore). Grab the latest release and see what is says.